# 1 core unstable when overclocking

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I have an AMD FX-8350 and I'm currently trying to overclock using ASUS AI Suite II. I have increased BLCK to 216MHz (from 200) and increased CPU Voltage to 1.38750V (from 1.35V). I have run Prime95 and noticed that logical core #5 always fails on the overclock (although it runs fine at stock speeds/voltages), but all other cores always remain stable.

Is there any way to stabilize it, by further increasing CPU Voltage, or CPU/NB Voltage, or something else? Or is this just my luck with the Silicon Lottery, and there is nothing I can do (apart from disabling the core for compute-sensitive programs, such as Folding @ Home)?

Comment: It  crashing at a higher frequency would explain why the chip got put in the speed bin it ended up in. Sounds like the silicon lottery to me.

Comment: @Mokubai So even upping the voltage won't help stabilise it?